# access data from json_encode

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Below is the code generated by json_encode() at the ajax page. Now, I want to retrieve the data (Title, ISBN, Authors...).  Can anyone give me a hand? I've looked at jQuery.parseJSON function but get confused.

```
{
    "9780077225957": {
        "Items_Data": {
            "Title": "Developing Management Skills: What Great Managers Know and Do",
            "Data_Source": "Amazon",
            "Item_ID": "1329",
            "ISBN": "9780077225957",
            "Authors": "Timothy Baldwin",
            "Edition": "1",
            "Year": "2007",
            "Publisher": "McGraw-Hill/Irwin",
            "Amazon_Thumb_URL": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pVf7GKujL._SL160_.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you retrieving this from $.getJSON ? and what do you want done with this data?  Creating elements? Objects?

Comment: @natedavisolds it's currently from pure ajax, but I think I can add dateType: json on my ajax. I use them for pure HTML.

Comment: so you are going to create an element in the DOM based on the JSON returned? Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assigning in a JavaScript variable will work though I think you need to change `9780077225957` as key at the very first because you wont be access it using (.) operator. I have changed that to `Book9780077225957` and working fine. Here is the code I have used

```
var book = { "Book9780077225957" : { "Items_Data": { "Title": "Developing Management Skills: What Great Managers Know and Do", "Data_Source": "Amazon", "Item_ID": "1329", "ISBN": "9780077225957", "Authors": "Timothy Baldwin", "Edition": "1", "Year": "2007", "Publisher": "McGraw-Hill/Irwin", "Amazon_Thumb_URL": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pVf7GKujL.SL160.jpg" } } };

alert(book.Book9780077225957.Items_Data.Title);
```

Comment: Though I think you need to you $.getJSON to retrieve data through Ajax :)

Answer (score 0):

I would looking to do something like:

```
var Books = {
    toElement: function(data) {
        if (data) {

            $book = $('<div></div>')
                .addClass('book');

            $('<span></span>').className("title").text(data.Title)appendTo($book);
            $('<span></span>').className("authors").text(data.Authors)appendTo($book);
            $('<span></span>').className("isbn").text(data.ISBN)appendTo($book);

            $book.appendTo($('#books'));            
        }
    }
};

$(function() {
     $("#Button1").click(function() {
        var params = [];
        $.getJSON("book_url.js", params, function(returnedJSON) {
            Books.toElement(returnedJSON.Items_Data);           
        });

     });
});
```

I am not sure what the first element in the JSON will be.  It may not be returnedJSON.Items_Data.  For some reason I am thinking that the first level is ignored.  But I could be thinking about something else.

Hope this helps.